# You cannot combine --squash with --no-ff

Tags: git

ブランチを切って作業をし、作業が一通り完了したため`master`へ`git merge --squash <ブランチ名>`したところ`You cannot combine --squash with --no-ff.`のエラーが出ました。

`--squash`と`--no-ff`の違いは理解しているつもりですが、このエラー文で検索をかけても具体的な解決案が出てきませんでした。

ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 本当に`git merge --squash <ブランチ名>`ですか？`--no-ff`も一緒に指定したのではないのですね？gitconfigでmerge.ffの設定はどうなっていますか？

Comment: Kenji Noguchiさん。gitconfigのmergeの設定を```ff = false```にしていました…完全にKenji Noguchiさんの推測通りです…ご迷惑お掛けしました…

Answer (score 1):

`gitconfig`の設定を確認したところ、`merge`の項目で`ff = false`になっていたのが原因でした。

---

この回答は [@塩士亮平 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38873/you-cannot-combine-squash-with-no-ff#comment39233_38873) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しました。